# Mongoose field one to many relationship

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema( {

  username: String,
  fname: String,
  sname: String,
  googleId: String,
  phone: String,
  password: String,
  email: String
 
 });

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

const expenditureSchema = new mongoose.Schema( {

    expenditureCategory: String,
    username:{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:"User"}
  
   });
const Expenditure = new mongoose.model("Expenditure", expenditureSchema);
```

This is the data am trying saving.

```
const item1 = new Expenditure (
 
  {

  expenditureCategory : "Giving",
  username:userProfile
 
});
```

`userProfile` is getting from `req.user.username` passport session

I am getting the following error

> Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters

Comment: Is there a typo in `username: userProfile` line and you mean `userid: userProfile` ??

Comment: there is no `username` on Expenditure scheme, did you mean `userid`. Is `userProfile` a valid mongo id?

Comment: my bad in the schema its not userid its username, but am still getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is wrong
The type of `username` in `expenditureSchema` is an `ObjectId`.
You can save `id` of `userProfile`

And in DB Architecture. Relation with `id` of `User` collection instead of username

Comment: Thank you, it worked i had typos from my first try